# How to get facebook page's stream with facebook-android-sdk

Tags: android, facebook, stream

I followed steps here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android
but I really don't get how use Graph API to get a Page's stream (only news) for Android.

Someone can make me an example? I cannot also find a real good example online searching with Google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good Graph API explorer [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), getting a page info is simple as using GET request with the page id.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>
```

So you can use the Simple Sample found [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/simple)

```
//Page id for Bristol (my hometown) but could use something like 'cocacola'
String PAGE_ID="108700782494847"
mBristolPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  //get the request aysn and process JSON response with the Listener
  mAsyncRunner.request(PAGE_ID, new MyPageRequestListener());
}
});
```

To get the feed/news from a page put /feed on the end  [However you may require a auth_token to get news stream]

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>/feed
```